# Confusion on correct use of Async / Await

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

This is my implementation of async/await in Windows Forms Application

```
async Task<int> DoAysnc1()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return 3000;
}

async Task<int> DoAsync2()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return 5000;
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
    var doAsync1 = DoAysnc1();
    var doAsync2 = DoAysnc2();
    var async1 = await doAsync1;
    var async2 = await doAsync2;
    this.textBox1.Text = $"{async1} & {async2}";
}
```

After 5 seconds the result in the TextBox is "`3000 & 5000`".

But when I modify `button1_Click` like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
    var async1 = await DoAysnc1();
    var async2 = await DoAysnc2();
    this.textBox1.Text = $"{async1} & {async2}";
}
```

the result is the same but it takes 8 sec.

Why second version of `button1_Click` act as synchronous?

Comment: In second case you don't run `DoAsync2()` until `DoAsync1()` is finished. Isn't that clear? There is a nice picture on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) explaining what is happening behind `async/await`, study it please.

Comment: when take a reference to a `Task`, it starts executing! `await` says, when you're finished, re-enter my method here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/48/async-await#t=201607251201374786908

Comment: @Nicorus: The second result is not acting synchronously; it's acting *serially*. Synchronous means "blocking the calling thread"; serial means "one at a time".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the explanation of the difference:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "";
var doAsync1 = DoAysnc1();         // <--- Run DoAsync1
var doAsync2 = DoAysnc2();         // <--- Run DoAsync2
var async1 = await doAsync1;       // <--- wait for DoAsync1 to finish
var async2 = await doAsync2;       //<--- wait for DoAsync2 to finish
this.textBox1.Text = $"{async1} & {async2}";
```

While:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "";
var async1 = await DoAysnc1();          // <-- Run DoAsync1 and wait for it to be done
var async2 = await DoAysnc2();          // <-- Run DoAsync2 and wait for it to be done
this.textBox1.Text = $"{async1} & {async2}";
```

So in the first version, both tasks are running at the same time. While in the second version you never run the second task until the first is Completed.

I think reading this [Article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) is going to be a big plus for your knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

With some comments to make what actually happens more clear:

```
// Starts DoAsync1 asynchronously
var doAsync1 = DoAysnc1();

// Starts DoAsync2 asynchronously
var doAsync2 = DoAysnc2();

// From now on, both task are executing

// Wait for DoAsync1 completion
var async1 = await doAsync1;

// Wait for DoAsync2 completion
var async2 = await doAsync2;
```

For the second case:

```
// Starts DoAsync1 asynchronously, and wait for the task completion (3s)
var async1 = await DoAysnc1();

// Starts DoAsync2 asynchronously, and wait for the task completion (5s)
var async2 = await DoAysnc2();
```

Answer (score 2):

`DoAsync1` and `DoAsync2` return awaitable `Task`-objects. If you await them one by one then they are executed one after another (first wait for the first one to finish, then for the second one). In order to run them in parallel you can simply create the `Task`-objects first and wait for their results with `Task.WhenAll`.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = "";

    var task1 = DoAysnc1();
    var task2 = DoAysnc2();
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2)

    this.textBox1.Text = $"{task1.Result} & {task2.Result}";
}
```